# python - importing parent dir issues

Tags: python

I created with virtualenv a Foo project and I've some problem with importing the File module in test_file.py

This is my project directory

```
Foo/
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── testfile.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_gram.py
│   ├── util
│   │   ├── File.py
│   │   ├── Gram.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
└── NOTES
```

test_gram.py:

```
from app.util.File import loadDataFromPickle

listofdict = loadDataFromPickle(".....")
i = 0
for item in listofdict[:50]:
    print(item)
```

If I run test_gram, I am getting a ImportError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_gram.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app.util.File import loadDataFromPickle
ImportError: No module named 'app
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to change the virtualenv-path to Foo/app instead of Foo?

Comment: Python imports are now absolute by default and your app directory is not in `sys.path`. Try `from ..app.util.File import loadDataFromPickle`

Comment: I think you should move the `test_gram.py` to Foo/ (not too sure)

Comment: If I put  test_gram.py in app and i do from util.File import ............... It works, but it is cleaner to put tests in a tests directory.

Comment: @dhke What do you mean by from ..app.util.File import loadDataFromPickle

Answer (score 3):

If test_gram.py is in the tests folder, then the import line should be:

```
from ..util.File import loadDataFromPickle$
```

---

Another option is to use the `imp` module, which is usually suggested instead of appending the sys.path ([source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/2327328), including Python 3 version)

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

Comment: `imp` module is deprecated in favour of module `importlib`.

Answer (score 2):

```
from app.util.File import loadDataFromPickle
```

is an *absolute import*, meaning

1. go to `sys.path`
2. from any of the paths listed there
3. find the first one that has an `app` module.
4. Then import the `util` module from that `app` module.
5. ...

The tricky bit is the `sys.path`, which is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) as

> As initialized upon program startup, **the first item of this list, path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter.** If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), path[0] is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of PYTHONPATH.

So if you run `Foo/app/tests/test_gram.py`, `sys.path` starts with `.../Foo/app/tests/`. There's no `app` module anywhere below that directory, so you cannot import `app` using an absolute import (unless there's an `app` somewhere else on some `sys.path`).

As suggested in the comments and other answers, it is good practice to use *relative imports* in such situations:

```
from ..util.File import loadDataFromPickle
```

Relative imports are [relative to the current package/module](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html), not to the directories in `sys.path`.

**Edit:**

However, relative imports will not work when running the script directly from the command line, as python will complain that the `''` module has not been imported (`Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative importSystemError: Parent module ''`). Well, that's because the parent modules (`tests` and `''`) are not loaded when running the script directly and the importer rightly assumes they should be.

One trick is to [run the test script as a module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/):

```
python -m app.tests.test_gram.py
```

This will most likely require some changes to the test script, at least having

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    [...]
```

inside the script. See also [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) for more details.

As a suggestion, you might want to convert the test script to using [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), anyway.

Comment: Thanks for info. The solution of appending the app dir to the sys.path suggested by a.j works in this particular, but it seems not useful if there are a lot of testfiles. So I tried to import module with the relative path like @dhke suggested. But I Get the following error: SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative importSystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

I'm just experimenting to look for a useful hierarchy

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: Better than appending the sys.path is to use the `imp` module - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/2327328)

Comment: My intention is to start with ttd&unittest, but because python is pretty new for me, I wanted to get a good hierarchy first. Now I'm looking for  the best way to test modules (importing: I've read that some people uses imp to add the 'modules' path. Others says you need to export the 'module dir' in PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

You are in `test_gram.py` which is in a child folder of `app`. Thus, when you try to import `app`, it looks for `app` in `tests`, which it isn't there:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Foo/app/util')

from File import loadDataFromPickle
```

Comment: Better than appending the sys.path is to use the `imp` module - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/2327328)

Answer (score 0):

In this case I just needed to run the test (Foo/app/tests/test_gram.py) from toplevel directory and not from the test directory like I did.